# Guest user randomly created on my Mac, after setting up Find My Mac

Tags: macos, icloud, find-my-mac

How do I disable the guest user? Is there a reason why it gets created? It won't mess up any of my files or data on my computer right? Is find my Mac suppose to randomly create it?

Comment: The creation is not random, it's intentional. You choose whether or not to enable it in sys prefs/user accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Find My Mac enabled, someone who found the computer could sign into the guest user, which could then be located via iCloud. The guest user is a feature of the operating system which allows people to temporarily use your computer but not save any files.

You can go into Users&Groups System Preferences and disable it, for more details see [this article](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18883)

Just make sure *you* don't sign into it and expect files you save to still be there after restarting the computer :)